# Is it possible to run a command when stopping a Docker container?

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` to organize containers for a JS application.
The source container sports `command: npm start`, pretty standard, to spin up the live application. However, that timeouts when I ask it to stop.

I was wondering if it's possible to have `docker-compose stop` to run a command inside the container - that could properly terminate the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose stop` just sends a `SIGTERM` to your container and if it does not stop after 10secs (configurable) `SIGKILL` follows. So if you want to customize this behavior, you should handle signal inside your `entrypoint` (if you have one).